# How to set database migration strategy to manual in Keycloak 18

Tags: mysql, keycloak, quarkus, data-migration

According to the Keycloak Docs - Upgrading section ([Upgrading](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html#manual-relational-database-migration)), using `--spi-connections-jpa-default-migration-strategy=manual` would write all the necessary queries needed for database migration to a SQL file and would exit the server.

I have tried this config as an in-line argument as well as tried adding it in to the `keycloak.conf` file but still when I start the server it automatically migrates the database and starts up.

Have I missed anything? or is there another way to do this?

Also what's the default location where this SQL file will be available at once it is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at PR https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/11110

It is named differently, no "default" provider but "quarkus" is used:

--spi-connections-jpa-quarkus-migration-strategy=manual"

it may change in future according to comments.

Update, because of expected change!!!

The final spi name is with "**legacy**" now, refer to https://www.keycloak.org/server/db

--spi-connections-jpa-**legacy**-migration-strategy=manual

Comment: For me this didn't work. I was migrating fro keycloak 16 to 21 with postgres database. My command-line kc.bat start-dev --features scripts --http-enabled=false --https-port=8443  --https-key-store-file=...  --https-key-store-password=... --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true --log-level WARNING  --log file --spi-connections-jpa-quarkus-migration-strategy=manual --log console
Can somebodyy giv me a hint?

Comment: in meantime they changed once more the spi name. I updated the solution